# Github get Neccessary Libraries with cloning

Tags: c++, github, libraries

Is it possible with cloning a repo(C++) to get all dependencys?
For example if i clone a project which have the dependency Boost all dependencys will be managed within the cloning process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, github repos aren't neccessarily self contained. If they need any dependencies you have to install these separately at your development environment.

Answer (score 1):

That depends *entirely* on how the project in question manages its dependencies.

There's no universal solution / answer.